# Loading content with getBoundingClientRect

Tags: javascript

`if (element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom < window.innerHeight) {...}`

I'm loading content when scrolling to the bottom of the page. The problem is, at a certain point `getBoundingClientRect().bottom` ain't smaller than `window.innerHeight` - `640.390625 640`. I don't know where this slightly bigger number comes from. There's no margin or anything else preventing the container getting to the end of the page.

If you need more details, just ask and I'll add it.

EDIT: The problem just seems to appear when simulating mobile devices in the dev tools. As a workaround I just substracted 25 from `getBoundingClientRect().bottom` but this seems ugly.

Comment: Have you tried using ***ResizeObserver***?

Comment: @Joshua Just looked at it. Sadly not exactly what I need.

Comment: Why doesn't it fit your needs?

Comment: @Joshua I need to load elements when scrolling to the bottom. Therefore I have to detect when I get to the bottom of the element. that's not possible with the observer cause it's just detecting changes of the dimension of the element itself.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say ***IntersectionObserver***.

Comment: @Joshua That sounds like I could try it, thanks. If you add it as the asnwer I could mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `IntersectionObserver`. You can read up on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)